# How do I pass a list of values in postgres function without using array

Tags: postgresql, list, plpgsql

I need to create a function where the input parameter is a list of values with a single column:

```
Column1
Abc
Xyz
Mno
    
    

Create or replace function dummy(my_list <list of 3 values>) returns refcursor as
    .......
    $$
       Open ref for select * from table1 where col1 in (my_list);

       Return ref
    End;
```

Can someone please let me know how I can do this without using an array?

Also please let me know how I can call it in pgAdmin.

EDIT :
Below is the code I am trying:

```
CREATE TYPE public.row1 AS
    (col1 character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xyz(
    i_a character varying,
    i_b row1[] DEFAULT array[NULL]::row1[])
    RETURNS refcursor
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
ref refcursor='o_c'; -- Declare a cursor variable
BEGIN
    OPEN ref FOR
    select * from es_forecast_period_ngf a where a.fiscal_quarter_name=i_a and a.fiscal_period in any(i_b.col1);
RETURN ref; -- Return the cursor to the caller
END;
$BODY$;
    
    calling mechanism :


BEGIN;
    SELECT xyz('Q3 FY2031',array[row('Q3-M1'),row('Q3-M2')]::row1[]);
    FETCH ALL in "o_c";
    COMMIT;
    
    error while compiling:


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "any"
    LINE 13: ... a.fiscal_quarter_name=i_a and a.fiscal_period in any(i_b.co...
                                                                  ^
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 375
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by not using an array?

Comment: We are currently migrating our entire oracle database to postgres. In oracle we have functions where we are returning or taking refcursor as input and applying some business logic to it. For this particular scenario, we have an API Mulesoft layer which directly fires the query to oracle like : select * fron table where col1 in #payload. Payload here is a list of values. We want to have everything in function so that API doesnt run any queries directly. Hence we want a function where the input will be payload which is a list of values and we will return a cursor to api with the results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another idea is to pass the list of values as *text* that can be cast to array. Details on array syntax [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html).
Assuming that the list consists of text values then:

```sql
create or replace function dummy(my_list text) returns refcursor as
........
open ref for select * from table1 where col1 = any(('{'||my_list||'}')::text[]);
```

Here you always pass the list of values as text.
If integer values then `('{'||my_list||'}')::text[]` becomes `('{'||my_list||'}')::integer[]` and so on for other data types. Please also note that the list of values text needs to be properly escaped.

Comment: Hi Stefavov.sm, can you see my latest edit and suggest

Comment: `('{'||my_list||'}')::text[]` can be simplified to `(string_to_array(my_list, ','))`

Comment: @GoutamSahoo change `in any` to `= any`

Comment: @GoutamSahoo I guess that `es_forecast_period_ngf.fiscal_period` is of type text. Why shall you need `i_b row1[]` instead of `i_b text[]` and `select xyz('Q3 FY2031', 'Q3-M1, Q3-M2')` using my suggestion above?

Comment: This is a sample where we are using a type with 1 column. But eventually we will have 2d arrays(for example a type with col1 and col2)  in which we would only want to check for 1 column (lets say col2)

Comment: @GoutamSahoo I see. You can still represent an array of record types as a text string. See `create type tp as (s text, i integer); select '{"(Q3-M1, 1)","(Q3-M2, 2)"}'::tp[];`

Comment: Agreed,lets say i pass this to a function. And inside function i need to do select * from table1 where column1 in tp.s . How do i do that

Comment: @GoutamSahoo Given i_b is an array of tp then `column1 = any(array(select t.s from unnest(i_b) t))`

Comment: @GoutamSahoo Glad to hear that.Then accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a variadic function (this example uses `integer` and is written in SQL, but that makes no difference):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dummy(VARIADIC args integer[]) RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT count(*)
FROM generate_series(1, 9) AS i
WHERE i = ANY (args)';

SELECT dummy(1, 5, 12);

 dummy 
-------
     2
(1 row)

SELECT dummy(1, 2, 5, 6, 9);

 dummy 
-------
     5
(1 row)
```

Such a function can be called with any number of  arguments, but they all have to have the same type (unless you want to code C).

The values passed to such a variadic argument (which must be the last in the argument list) form an array inside the function body.

Comment: So there is no there way of doing this without using an array? Can you please let me know how i will call this function with 2 inputs. 1st is a varchar with username and the 2nd will be an array as per your suggestion with multiple values. Query inside function will be: select * from table1 where col1=username and col2 in array_list; result will be returned in refcursor. Can you please tell me how will i call this function in PgAdmin with some sample inputs to test it. Also can you tell me if i can use a type for this? Does type only hold 1 record??

Comment: Also i want to see how i can do this using plpgsql

Comment: What if i want to pass an object will multiple rows and columns? How do i do that? Also is array the only way to do this?

Comment: Sure. Since each data type automatically has a corresponding array type in PostgreSQL, that is no problem.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, can you see my latest edit and suggest

Comment: Sorry, that would be a different question. But basic syntax errors are too trivial. There is no `IN ANY`; perhaps you mean `= ANY`.